# Optional argument not recognized

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to learn how to use argparse and and am running into an issue when trying to implement an optional argument. Here's what I have:

```
import argparse

def main(num1, num2=None):
    if num1 and num2:
        print(num1 + num2)
    else:
        print(num1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Add some numbers')
    parser.add_argument('num1', help='The first number')
    parser.add_argument('-num2', help='The second number', action='store_true')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args.num1, args.num2)
```

I'm sure it's a very simple issue, but I am getting this error when I pass in arguments 2 and 3 on the command line:

```
usage: argparse_test.py [-h] [-num2] num1
argparse_test.py: error: unrecognized arguments: 3
```

Why is the argument "unrecognized"?

Comment: When you say `action='store_true'` means that the argument is a boolean flag. So it must only be passed by name (with no value). Only looking at num2 you out use your program like `program -num2` and argparse would set num2 to True, but you can not give a value (so no `program -num2 2` or `program 2`)

Comment: What did you expect from the 'store_true' for `-num2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've only defined one positional argument (`num1`). If you're passing in two positional arguments, you would expect that error message. `-num2` is an option, and doesn't take any arguments. In other words, these are valid invocations:

```
python argparse_test.py -num2 1
python argparse_test.py 1
```

Anything else is not.

If you want to accept multiple positional arguments, you'd want
something like:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Add some numbers')
parser.add_argument('num1', help='The first number')
parser.add_argument('num2', nargs='?', help='The second number')
```

This defines `num1` as a required positional argument, and `num2` as
an positional argument that will consume 0 or 1 values.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention that arguments are type of string, so you have to cast them from string to int, otherwise, num1 + num2 will append two strings.

Your program should look like:

```
import argparse

def main(num1, num2=None):
    if num1 and num2:
        print(int(num1) + int(num2))
    else:
        print(num1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Add some numbers')
    parser.add_argument('num1', help='The first number')
    parser.add_argument('-num2', help='The second number')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args.num1, args.num2)
```